# How to make table width auto with d3.js

Tags: css, d3.js

I'm doing my first page with d3 for several reasons at work. in a similar page I create a table with handlebars, I have the table width and the overflow-x on the div containing it to auto and on the handlebars page when the table is created the columns automatically adjust width so that the values in the drop downs can be seen and when necessary a scroll appears. I can't do fixed width in this page any more than the old page because columns are dynamic and I already checked the overflow-x was not the problem by trying scroll. The table width is just not widening, it is remaining at 100% of the page width and shrinking the columns.
How do I change it so that the columns (namely the tds with selects) maintain their width and the table auto adjusts to flow to the right?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style>
        .div-therightone {
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        .table-therightone {
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainMenu" runat="Server">
 <div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="div-therightone">
            <div id="alert"></div>
            <table id="products" class="table table-therightone">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-row-add"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>Add Item</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-save-all"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-floppy-o"></i>Save Items</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainMenu" runat="Server">



<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadProductsGrid(products) {
        var table = d3.select('#products');
        var tableBody = table.select('tbody');
        var tableHeader = table.select('thead');

        var tableRows = tableBody
            .selectAll('tr')
            .data(products, function (d, i) { return i; });

        //new rows
        var newRows = tableRows.enter()
            .append('tr')
            .classed('selectable', (d) => {
            });


                newRows.merge(newRows)
                    .call(AppendInput)
                    .call(AppendSelect);

    function AppendInput(rows) {
        var input = rows.append('td')
            .attr('column', 'Product Number')
            .append('input');
        input.attr('value', (d) => d.productNumber)
            .attr('field', 'productNumber')
            .classed('form-control', true)
            .on('input', Input)
            .on('blur', Blur);
    };
    function AppendSelect(rows) {
        var myOptions = cache.stuffInSelect.filter((d) => d.IsValid && !d.IsInvalid);
        var select = rows.append('td')
            .attr('column', 'Select Title')
            .append('select')
            .classed('form-control', true)
            .on('change', Change);
        select
            .attr('field', 'selectField');
        select
            .selectAll('option')
            .data(myOptions)
            .enter()
            .append('option')
            .attr('value', (d) => { return d.SelectValue; })
            .text((d) => { return d.selectDescription; });           
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add some more code and example data, as it feels quite a bit incomplete and unsolvable at this stage.

Comment: other than the if statements that determine which columns show up this is all of the pertinent code that keeps this anonymous (ei. naming one method AppendSelect instead of, if say the info was color and size, two similar methods called AppendSelect and AppendSize that do the same this with different data sets to populate in the selects). If something is missing I may be missing something necessary without realizing it which solves my problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce the css issues without some dummy data to feed to produce the table. That is the reason I am asking to show some example data. Alternatively you could make a block at blockbuilder.org or a fiddle on jsfiddle.net.